# Как запустить webgl код без использования текстуры?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Есть такой интересный код , выполненный с помощью webGl - [codepen](https://codepen.io/team/Atcom/pen/dWwGKa)

```js
var canvas;
var gl;
var realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio;
var displayWidth;
var displayHeight;
var rings;
var createdMetaballs = [];
var assetsIndexToLoad = 0;
var assetsToLoad = [
    {path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-183/', src: 'noise3.png', name: 'noise3', type: 'texture'}
];
var assets = {};

window.onload = preloadAssets;

function preloadAssets() {


    function checkIfAllAssetsAreLoaded() {
        if (assetsIndexToLoad < assetsToLoad.length) {
            loadAssetIndex(assetsIndexToLoad);
        }
        else {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    function loadAssetIndex(index) {
        var objectToLoad = assetsToLoad[index];

        switch (objectToLoad.type) {
            case 'texture':
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function(event) {
                    assets[objectToLoad.name] = this;
                    assetsIndexToLoad++;
                    checkIfAllAssetsAreLoaded();
                };
            image.crossOrigin = '';
                image.src = objectToLoad.path + objectToLoad.src;
                break;
        }
    }

    loadAssetIndex(assetsIndexToLoad);
}

function initialize(){

    canvas = document.getElementById('metaball-canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var glConfig = {
        premultipliedAlpha: true,
        antialias: true,
        depth:true,
        alpha: true
    }
    
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', glConfig) || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', glConfig);
  
    if(!gl){
        console.error('cannot find gl', gl);
        return;
    }
    displayWidth  = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientWidth  * realToCSSPixels);
    displayHeight = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientHeight * realToCSSPixels);

    var minSpeed = 0.2;
    var maxSpeed = 2.5;
    var minMultiplierArcX = -.25;
    var maxMultiplierArcX = .75;
    var minMultiplierArcY = -.25;
    var maxMultiplierArcY = .25;
    var scale = 1.0;

    var metaballsGroup1 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:26 * scale, centerOffsetY:155 * scale, radius: 70 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-110 * scale, centerOffsetY:10 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:12 * scale, centerOffsetY:-114 * scale, radius: 48 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-300 * scale, centerOffsetY:20 * scale, radius: 160 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-570 * scale, centerOffsetY:-20 * scale, radius: 50 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.2}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.35}, {color:'#40204c', stop:.55}, {color:'#e24926', stop:.75}, {color:'#40204c', stop:1.0}], false, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup2 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:-290 * scale, centerOffsetY:60 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-100 * scale, centerOffsetY:45 * scale, radius: 70 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-60 * scale, centerOffsetY:60 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:160 * scale, centerOffsetY:170 * scale, radius: 90 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:310 * scale, centerOffsetY:40 * scale, radius: 40 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:450 * scale, centerOffsetY:-120 * scale, radius: 50 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:230 * scale, centerOffsetY:-240 * scale, radius: 70 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:320 * scale, centerOffsetY:-130 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:110 * scale, centerOffsetY:-70 * scale, radius: 80 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },

            { centerOffsetX:-1070 * scale, centerOffsetY:-500 * scale, radius: 20 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(0.07, 0.014), t:0.0, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(30.0, 30.0), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(10.0, 10.0) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.0}, {color:'#e24926', stop:0.3}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.4}, {color:'#40204c', stop:.7}], true, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup3 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:410 * scale, centerOffsetY:-120 * scale, radius: 18 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:340 * scale, centerOffsetY:-200 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:200 * scale, centerOffsetY:-190 * scale, radius: 40 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:250 * scale, centerOffsetY:-280 * scale, radius: 16 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.56}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.63}, {color:'#40204c', stop:.7}], false, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup4 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:-410 * scale, centerOffsetY:-270 * scale, radius: 28 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-490 * scale, centerOffsetY:-230 * scale, radius: 34 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-470 * scale, centerOffsetY:-320 * scale, radius: 40 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-470 * scale, centerOffsetY:320 * scale, radius: 40 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-430 * scale, centerOffsetY:360 * scale, radius: 30 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.1}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.20}, {color:'#40204c', stop:.4}], false, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup5 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:-500 * scale, centerOffsetY:-100 * scale, radius: 24 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:30 * scale, centerOffsetY:-120 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:480 * scale, centerOffsetY:170 * scale, radius: 21 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.25}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.60}, {color:'#40204c', stop:0.78}], true, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup6 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:820 * scale, centerOffsetY:20 * scale, radius: 200 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:480 * scale, centerOffsetY:30 * scale, radius: 70 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:500 * scale, centerOffsetY:-10 * scale, radius: 65 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:1080 * scale, centerOffsetY:30 * scale, radius: 35 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:400 * scale, centerOffsetY:160 * scale, radius: 55 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:350 * scale, centerOffsetY:-120 * scale, radius: 75 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },

            { centerOffsetX:1670 * scale, centerOffsetY:500 * scale, radius: 15 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(0.21, 0.22), t:13.0, arcMultiplierX:30.0, arcMultiplierY:6.0 },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.0}, {color:'#e24926', stop:0.7}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.8}, {color:'#40204c', stop:1.0}], false, false)
    };
    var metaballsGroup7 = {
        metaballs:[
            { centerOffsetX:-930 * scale, centerOffsetY:40 * scale, radius: 30 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-800 * scale, centerOffsetY:90 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-640 * scale, centerOffsetY:270 * scale, radius: 50 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-590 * scale, centerOffsetY:150 * scale, radius: 90 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-400 * scale, centerOffsetY:240 * scale, radius: 40 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-300 * scale, centerOffsetY:120 * scale, radius: 35 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-450 * scale, centerOffsetY:50 * scale, radius: 70 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-590 * scale, centerOffsetY:-40 * scale, radius: 60 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
            { centerOffsetX:-370 * scale, centerOffsetY:-70 * scale, radius: 50 * scale, speed: getRandomFloat(minSpeed, maxSpeed), t:Math.random() * 200, arcMultiplierX:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcX, maxMultiplierArcX), arcMultiplierY:getRandomFloat(minMultiplierArcY, maxMultiplierArcY) },
        ],
        texture:generateGradientTexture([{color:'#e24926', stop:0.2}, {color:'#c8246c', stop:.4}, {color:'#40204c', stop:.7}], true, false)
    };

    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup6));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup7));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup2));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup1));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup3));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup4));
    createdMetaballs.push(new Metaballs(gl, metaballsGroup5));

    for (var i = 0; i < createdMetaballs.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(createdMetaballs[i].fadeIn, i * 200);
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onWindowMouseMove);
  
    resizeGL(gl);

    step();
}

function generateGradientTexture(colors, vertical, debug) {

    colors = colors || [{color:'#000000', stop:0.0}, {color:'#FFF000', stop:.5}, {color:'#642054', stop:1.0}];
    vertical = vertical !== undefined ? vertical : false;

    var size = 512;

    // create canvas
    var textureCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    textureCanvas.width = size;
    textureCanvas.height = size;

    if(debug == true){
        textureCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        textureCanvas.style.top = '0px';
        textureCanvas.style.left = '0px';
        document.body.appendChild(textureCanvas);
    }

    // get context
    var context = textureCanvas.getContext( '2d' );

    // draw gradient
    context.rect( 0, 0, size, size );

    var grd = vertical ? context.createLinearGradient(0, size, 0, 0) : context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, size, 0);
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
        grd.addColorStop(colors[i].stop, colors[i].color);
    }
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);

    return textureCanvas;
}



function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function onWindowResize(event){
    canvas.width   = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height  = canvas.clientHeight;
   
  
    resizeGL(gl);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
}

function onWindowMouseMove(event){
    createdMetaballs.forEach(function(metaball){
        metaball.handleMouseMove(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    });
}

function resizeGL(gl) {
    realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio;

    // Lookup the size the browser is displaying the canvas in CSS pixels
    // and compute a size needed to make our drawingbuffer match it in
    // device pixels.
    displayWidth  = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientWidth  * realToCSSPixels);
    displayHeight = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientHeight * realToCSSPixels);

    // Check if the canvas is not the same size.
    if (gl.canvas.width  !== displayWidth ||
        gl.canvas.height !== displayHeight) {

        // Make the canvas the same size
        gl.canvas.width  = displayWidth;
        gl.canvas.height = displayHeight;
    }

    gl.viewport(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

    createdMetaballs.forEach(function(metaball){
        metaball.handleResize(displayWidth, displayHeight);
    });
}

var step = function() {
    
    createdMetaballs.forEach(function(metaball){
        metaball.updateSimulation();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dots{
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-183/dots-transparent.png);
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .1;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.grad {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #152a8e, #b1376c); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #152a8e, #b1376c); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #152a8e, #b1376c); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #152a8e, #b1376c); /* Standard syntax */
}
.metaball-canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-183/Metaballs.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexMetaballs">
 attribute vec2 position;
  void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
 }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentMetaballs">
 precision highp float;
  const int NUM_METABALLS = 15;

  uniform vec3 metaballs[15];
  uniform vec2 uResolution;
  uniform sampler2D uColorSampler;
  uniform sampler2D uNoiseSampler;
  uniform float uTime;
  
 void main(){
   float x = gl_FragCoord.x;
    float y = gl_FragCoord.y;
    float v = 0.0;
    float radius = 2.0;
    float speed = 1.5;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_METABALLS; i++) {
     vec3 mb = metaballs[i];
   float dx = mb.x - x;
   float dy = mb.y - y;

      float r = mb.z;
      v += r*r/(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  }

    vec4 color;
    if (v > 1.0) {
     vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uColorSampler, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / uResolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y) );
      vec4 noiseColor = (texture2D(uNoiseSampler, gl_FragCoord.xy / 100.0 )) / 1.;
      float l = length(noiseColor);
      if(l > 1.05){
       vec4 mixedColor = textureColor + (noiseColor * 0.001);
    color = mixedColor;
   }
      else{
       //discard;
        color = textureColor * 0.85;
   }
  }
    else {
     discard;
  }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 0.8);
 }

</script>


<div class="wrapper grad">
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <canvas id="metaball-canvas" class="metaball-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Но если использовать локально или на другом ресурсе этот код, то появляется ошибка:

> Access to Image at
>   'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-183/noise3.png' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://s.codepen.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Код соответственно не работает.

Если я правильно понимаю, то  `var assetsToLoad = [ {path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-183/', src: 'noise3.png', name: 'noise3', type: 'texture'} ];` отвечает за текстуру фигур?!

Пытаюсь закомментировать

```
        // window.onload = preloadAssets;

        // function preloadAssets() {


        //     function checkIfAllAssetsAreLoaded() {
        //         if (assetsIndexToLoad < assetsToLoad.length) {
        //             loadAssetIndex(assetsIndexToLoad);
        //         }
        //         else {
        //             initialize();
        //         }
        //     }

        //     function loadAssetIndex(index) {
        //         var objectToLoad = assetsToLoad[index];

        //         switch (objectToLoad.type) {
        //             case 'texture':
        //                 var image = new Image();
        //                 image.onload = function(event) {
        //                     assets[objectToLoad.name] = this;
        //                     assetsIndexToLoad++;
        //                     checkIfAllAssetsAreLoaded();
        //                 };
        //             image.crossOrigin = '';
        //                 image.src = objectToLoad.path + objectToLoad.src;
        //                 break;
        //         }
        //     }

        //     loadAssetIndex(assetsIndexToLoad);
        // }
```

и напрямую запустить `initialize();`, но тогда появляется другая ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the
>   signature provided.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли использовать данный код без использования текстуры (или заменить данную текстуру на какую-нибудь доступную не только на codepen) и можно ли как-то запустить локально? [Fork проект](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/yvNaWJ)

Comment: _Но если использовать локально или на другом ресурсе этот код, то появляется ошибка:_ - а в сниппете вроде нормально все выводится. А хотя да, в консоли ошибка :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в `origin:null`. Данное значение устанавливается при запуске локального файла и при отсутствии у iframe в атрибуте `sandbox` значения `allow-same-origin`.

Именно поэтому пример не работает в сниппете.

При этом он вполне работает на codepen и [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cqn7urh/).

Интересно, что просто вставить эту картинку на страницу можно, и она покажется, но в этом случае ее нельзя будет использовать для операций с canvas.

Comment: т.е. решения нет?

Comment: @HamSter, решение - локальный сервер любой. Либо использование сторонних ресурсов, типа codepen и jsfiddle, в которых нужные настройки у iframe

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html

Comment: Возможно Вам будет интересен мой ответ =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, уже посмотрел :-)

Answer (score 1):

Про **cors** `Grungy` все правильно написал, однако есть обходные пути, подходит это Вам или нет, решайте сами, мое дело предложить...

---

Не прикрепляю сниппет т.к. такой большой сюда не лезет, я упаковал текстуру шума в в `base64` (при помощи [base64-image.de](https://www.base64-image.de/)) и добавил вместо `url` картинки - и все заработало в сниппете, но сохранить его не получается, вот ссылка на [codepen](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/RObzax).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос можно ли это сделать без текстуры - да можно сгенерировать такую текстуру на лету, либо использовать математическую функцию шума.

PS: Редактор ругается на ссылки на codepen без фрагментов кода, поэтому привожу один кусок, как раз который поменял:

```
var assetsToLoad = [
    {path: '', src: 'data:image/png;base64,iV....', name: 'noise3', type: 'texture'}
];
```